# Accessing IHttpContextAccessor in starup.cs Configure crashes my app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

In my startup.cs Configure I need to get the domain name.
I do this by injecting IHttpContextAccessor in the Configure like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    [...]

    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    [...]

}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IHttpContextAccessor httpContext, DBContext dbContext)
{

    [...]

    var host = httpContext.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host;
    var country = dbContext.Countries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Domain == host);
    /*
    var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(country.CultureInfo);
    cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = country.CurrencySymbol;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
    */

    [...]

    app.UseMvc();

}
```

If I remove the `var host = httpContext.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host;` the app builds fine, but when it's present, the building of the app breaks (dotnet crashed) in VS Mac.

It seems that `HttpContext` is null, because `var host = httpContext.HttpContext?.Request.Host.Host;` don't crashes the app.

What am I missing?

Comment: `HttpContext` exists (makes sense) only during http request processing (on the pipeline or when a service is called from the pipeline). When `Configure` runs, there is nothing alike.

Comment: So there's no way to get the domain from the startup?

Comment: @Mads No, not really. `Request.Host.Host` will include the domain name the client used to address your server. Your server may be externally reachable via www.example.com, which would be what Request.Host.Host contains, whereas in your local network the same server may be reachable as myserver.local.

Comment: @ckuri that was also what I wanted, really, because I have language specific settings per domain. But if it's not possible, I'll do it in a PageFilter then.

Comment: @Mads take a look on [Localization Culture Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization-extensibility?view=aspnetcore-3.0)